# AutoLayout Xcode 7 - Constraints have different impact in landscape and portrait mode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have an issue with AutoLayouting in Xcode for an universalapp.

The start screen has a UILabel on the top and a UIImageView below.
I had a vertical-space-constraint from the UILabel.top to the TopLayoutGuide with 0 and vertical-space-constraint from the UIImageView.top to the UILabel.bottom with 0 as well.
Both, UILabel and UIImageView, have a fix height.

Now on the iPhone-Portrait-mode everything looks fine:
[iPhone - Portrait](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3810940/forenfotos/stack/autolayout/iphone_port.png)

But when rotating to landscape-mode, the statusbar disappears (standard-procedure since iOS7) and the UIImageView moves to the top, the UILabel is no longer visible: [iPhone - Landscape](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3810940/forenfotos/stack/autolayout/iphone_land.png)

On the iPad it's different in another way. In both modes, the UILabel is not visible and the UIImageView is on the top under the statusbar.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Have you set your constraints up on a compact size class by mistake?

Comment: No. I only worked on Any/Any size classes till now.